# Second order tensor field visualization software

Tags: visualization, tensor

Is there an overview available over tensor visualization software?

My personal preference is:

A software which is free, well documented, and offers visualization techniques for different physical second order (or higher-order) tensor fields.

Some modules that I would be interested in

- Hyperstreamlines ([eigenvector integration method](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.5555/951087.951115))
- Geodesics as direction, instead of eigenvectors
- Topological methods (e.g handling of equal eigenvalues, i.e [degenerate points](https://cgl.ethz.ch/teaching/scivis_common/Literature/DelmarcelleHesselink94.pdf), extraction of [Finite Lyapunov exponent](https://georgehaller.com/reprints/smallestFTLE.pdf))
- Tensor ellipsoids
- Texture based visualization ([HyperLIC](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1250379),[Physical based method](https://web.archive.org/web/20170809103936/http://www.zib.de/hotz/publications/paper/hotz04_physicalTensorTexture.pdf))
- Handling of asymmetric tensor fields (decomposition of tensor field into symmetric and anti-symmetric parts, and re-glueing of the resulting visualization, or a [direct approach](http://www.sci.utah.edu/%7Echengu/Publications/hybridtensorvis_vis11.pdf))

Depending on the physical property of the tensor field, different methods are required to visualize the data.

I know about about [Mayavi](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_pipeline_other_functions.html#hyper-streamline), but there is almost no documentation available for the tensor module, and the module is limited to visualization of a hyperstreamline (singular). The GUI is buggy, and the scripting options seem limited.

There appears to be a very dismal selection for visualization of tensor fields.

Answer (score 5):

The program [VisIt](http://www.visitusers.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) can do plots of tensor ellipsoids, but I don't think it has anything for hyperstreamlines. While it does make nice plots, I've found VisIt hard to install, if not impossible on some platforms; I know people who have been desperate enough to set up a virtual machine for it, but I haven't done that myself. When it does work, I have found it to be better than Mayavi in terms of documentation and lack of bugs.

I've also tried to find software for visualizing 2nd-rank tensors, and I agree with you that the options are pretty slim.

Comment: I guess, at least, MayaVi is relatively easy to install. It is interesting to read that VisIt can plot tensor glyphs. It is a shame though, that is the only option available (which, incidentally, does not work for asymmetric tensor fields - http://www.sci.utah.edu/~chengu/Publications/hybridtensorvis_vis11.pdf ).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest [Paraview](http://www.paraview.org/), that is similar to VisIt, since both are based on VTK. You can use Python Calculator and scripts (both based on Python), and are described in the [manual](http://www.paraview.org/paraview-downloads/download.php?submit=Download&version=v4.3&type=data&os=all&downloadFile=TheParaViewGuide-v4.3-CC-Edition.pdf).

You can also directly use [VTK](http://www.vtk.org/) that has a [Python interface](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Python). It already has implemented [hyperstreamlines](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkHyperStreamline.html) and the other algorithms can be implemented as *simple* scripts.

Comment: It looks like this may be the way to go. A shame that Paraview can not handle tensors already, besides user made plugins like http://www.paraview.org/Wiki/ParaView/User_Created_Plugins

Comment: It can handle tensor glyphs by itself, as far as I know.

Comment: And all tensor has a symmetric part. I don't think that there is a perfect visualization technique.

Comment: I have often used that argument my self. But sadly it is a cop out. There needs to be a unified way of treating tensors. If a "user" need to pre-process data in order to handle it, then that is already asking too much of the user. Another question is : How will you reunify the resulting visualization ? It is not a trivial task!

Comment: Here is the paraview tensor glyph documentation : http://www.paraview.org/ParaView/Doc/Nightly/www/py-doc/paraview.simple.TensorGlyph.html

Comment: As a "user", I don't utilize the same resources all the time. Most of the times I found the invariants of the tensor to be the thing of major interest (not always the same). Once in a while I need to visualize the principal directions of the tensor (as hyperstreamlines, for example).

Answer (score 1):

It is mostly an academic project, but you could take a look at TEEM http://teem.sourceforge.net/download/index.html. A tutorial for using it for second order tensor visualizations maybe found at http://cg.cs.uni-bonn.de/en/people/junprof-dr-thomas-schultz/visweek-tutorial-tensors-in-visualization/

Comment: I can see that the diffusion tensor module has been developed by Kindlemann. Which in it self is impressive. But, the tutorial link you provided does not deal with TEEM, but tutorial slides over the concept of tensor visualization.